3 Way Light Switch with black wire as "Common" and no ground wire?
I recently purchased a home built in the 80's and am in the process of switching out the 3 way flip switches with "smart" 3 way rocker light switches. I am having trouble figuring out how to wire this smart switch and may just call an electrician at this point. As you can see in the photos there are 2 black wires and 1 white. One of the black wires connects to the part of the switch that says "common" which I think is odd and the other white and black wire seem to be the travelers. In the box you can see some ground wires capped off and some more white wires capped off (not sure if those should be left alone). Honestly I'm just trying to figure out how I'm the world to connect it to my smart switch or if I should just give up and pay someone to come out because it shouldn't be this difficult (I did it on my previous home multiple times).


"In the box you can see..." Unfortunately, with the pictures given, no, we can't. Were you planning to add another picture?

In plastic boxes it is good to have a ground wire attached to the switch, even if switches are quite low being able to shock you.  Metal boxes usually ground the switch by the screws, so if the person who wired them was used to metal boxes, they might have just continued the practice.

There is only one issue here to figure out: Is common hot (line) or switched hot (load)?
To figure that out, turn on the breaker and then carefully check the common wire on the 3-way switch. If it shows voltage whether the switch is up or down then it is hot. If it only shows voltage when the switch is in one position then it is switched hot.
Assuming the common wire is hot (line), connect the new switch as follows:

Ground to the ground bundle
Traveler1 to one of the non-common (traveler) wires
Live to hot
Traveler2 to the other traveler wire
Neutral to the neutral white bundle

WARNING!
While the above directions apply to any "smart 3-way switch that uses both travelers and requires neutral and ground", this particular switch has many red flags regarding safety. Any switches installed in the US need to be properly listed/certified. Typically this means UL or ETL, though there are some other legitimate possibilities.

FCC is marked (relates to the WiFi) but no indication of UL, ETL or similar
"Live" is unusual terminology
Amazon page for this product has additional indications of problems

So check this carefully before installing. In the end, if it does not have UL, ETL or other legitimate listing then I recommend returning it and finding an alternative.
